# Sentence transformers - KeyError:__version__ error: What are some alternatives?

Tags: nlp, topic-modeling, sentence-transformers

I'm trying to use sentence transformer with all-miniLM-L6-v2 model for topic modeling but getting error as
KeyError:**version**

I have checked in the directory about all the downloaded files and it has all except rust_model.ot
I'm not sure if this is the cause of the error. Looking for help.

I made the package versions consistent for sentence transformers, torch and transformers

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively use the HuggingFace `transformers` package to use the `sentence-transformers` **all-miniLM-L6-v2** model through `AutoTokenizer`, `AutoModel`.

Begin by installing the HuggingFace transformers package
`pip install transformers`

Next, pass all the sentences as a list of strings to the `tokenizer()`.
The `AutoTokenizer`, `AutoModel` can download, load, and cache the `all-miniLM-L6-v2` model from the `sentence-transformers` since it is hosted on the [HuggingFace Hub](https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2).

```python
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F


# Input sentences/sequences for sentence embedding transformation.
sentences = ['This is the first sentence', 'This is the second sentence']

# Load the tokenizer and the model from HuggingFace Hub
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2')
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained('sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2')

# Run the tokenizer() to tokenize input sentences. Padding and truncation help preserve the dimension consistency. 
encoded_input = tokenizer(sentences, padding=True, truncation=True, return_tensors='pt')

# Generate the token embeddings
with torch.no_grad():
    model_output = model(**encoded_input)
```

Mean pooling can be computed with `mean_pooling()` that takes attention mask into consideration for correct averaging. Furthermore, the embeddings can be normalized using PyTorch's `normalize()`

```python
def mean_pooling(model_output, attention_mask):
    token_embeddings = model_output[0] #First element of model_output contains all token embeddings
    input_mask_expanded = attention_mask.unsqueeze(-1).expand(token_embeddings.size()).float()
    return torch.sum(token_embeddings * input_mask_expanded, 1) / torch.clamp(input_mask_expanded.sum(1), min=1e-9)


# Perform pooling
sentence_embeddings = mean_pooling(model_output, encoded_input['attention_mask'])

# Normalize embeddings
sentence_embeddings = F.normalize(sentence_embeddings, p=2, dim=1)

print("Sentence embeddings:")
print(sentence_embeddings)
```

`sentence_embeddings` will have a list of tensors with embeddings. These can be accessed by `sentence_embeddings[i]`, where i is the sentence index.

This reference example is also available on the [HuggingFace Hub](https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2).